# Why does $n = $n + $n not work

Tags: php, loops

I've tried out some code where I use a for loop in PHP to add up numbers but it seems to not work, how can be?

```
$n = 3; //or anything else
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
   $n = $n+$n;
}
echo $n;
```

This is just a test code for something else, but I'd still like it to work, please help

Comment: Describe how you want it to work...

Comment: Define "not work"! Nevertheless I do not think that this code will run, since you're missing some `$` symbols.

Comment: ;i<$n;i++) not a php variable i

Comment: ehm, the answer below worked, ehm, I screwed up pretty bad, thx for the time though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are increasing the loop ending condition $n inside the loop

this means it will never exit the loop.

this is an infinite loop, and wont ever print anything.

also your loop needs to be $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++

Comment: Maybe that's the goal. Who knows? :D

Comment: Ahaha, of course, pretty tired, thanks very much! How could I miss that?

Comment: solved it with another variable, thx again